# open the image when clicking it

Tags: android, imageview

i downloading images in an imageview from a json Server i need to open the image when clicking it and i send the position of the image to an activity that contain an imageview to Receive the sended photo but my problem is the imageView.setImageResource(list.get(ReceivedPosition)) take an intger and my list of photos from a custom obeject photos here the code

```
public class customfunny extends BaseAdapter {
Context c;
ArrayList<photos> sites;
public customfunny(Context c, ArrayList<photos> sites)
{
    this.c = c;
    this.sites = sites;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return sites.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return sites.get(i);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view==null)
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.funnyinflate,viewGroup,false);
    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    photos site = (photos) this.getItem(i);
    Picasso.with(c).load(site.getImage()).into(imageView);
    return view;
}
```

}

```
pulbic class Funny extends AppCompactActivity{String url = "http://javawy.fulba.com/yphotos.php";
ProgressDialog dialog;
ArrayList<photos> list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_funny);
    final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("photos");
                 list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject object1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String pw = object1.getString("image");
                    photos posts = new photos(pw);
                    list.add(posts);
                }
                customfunny adapter = new customfunny(Funny.this,list);
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Funny.this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Funny.this,SelectedImage.class);
            intent.putExtra("one",i);
        }
    });
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(Funny.this);
    dialog.setTitle("downloading");
    dialog.setMessage("wait......");
    dialog.show();
    Volley.newRequestQueue(Funny.this).add(stringRequest);
}}

public class SelectedImage extends AppCompactActivity{ @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selected_image);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("one");
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    imageView.setImageResource(new Funny().list.get(position));//compiler error
}}
```

Comment: What is the `photos` class?

Comment: Class contain a string and constructor take this string and the setter and getter of this string this string represent the json filed key:link of image

Comment: Then your code is very messed up.

Comment: what do you expect `new Funny().list.get(position)` to do?

Comment: Set the position of the photo sended from funny activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pas the actual URL in the intent, and then use Picasa to download the image into view. Picasa internally has already cached the image. There is no reason you are recreating the Funny Class and Adapter.

Comment: Thank you my friend I used Picasso before and I forget to use it in my code thank you very match